# Value load after render React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

the following react component loads the values after the render what I would like to do is that the componentDidMount content is loaded before the render and not after, how can I do it? Thank you

**Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Chart } from 'react-google-charts';
import { loadAttivita } from '../../services/attivita';

let columns = [
  { type: 'string', label: 'Task ID' },
  { type: 'string', label: 'Task Name' },
  { type: 'string', label: 'Resource' },
  { type: 'date', label: 'Start Date' },
  { type: 'date', label: 'End Date' },
  { type: 'number', label: 'Duration' },
  { type: 'number', label: 'Percent Complete' },
  { type: 'string', label: 'Dependencies' },
];

export const options = {
  height: 400,
  gantt: {
    trackHeight: 30,
  },
};
var rows = [];
/*var rows = [[
  '2014Spring',
  'prova',
  'autumn',
  new Date(2014, 2, 22),
  new Date(2014, 5, 20),
  null,
  100,
  null,
]];*/

class GaantView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rows: [],
      key: 0,
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    var valori = await loadAttivita();

    console.log('lunghezza valori: ' + valori.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < valori.length; i++) {
      console.log('descrizione: ' + valori[i].Descrizione);
      rows.push([
        '2014Spring',
        valori[i].Descrizione,
        'autumn',
        new Date(2014, 2, 22),
        new Date(2014, 5, 20),
        null,
        100,
        null,
      ]);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p style={{ color: 'white', alignContent: 'center' }}>Diagramma Gaant</p>{' '}
        <Chart chartType="Gantt" width="100%" height="100%" data={[columns, ...this.state.rows]} options={options} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    isFetching: state.auth.isFetching,
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
    errorMessage: state.auth.errorMessage,
  };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(GaantView));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the intended behavior, the component will mount and render at least once *then* mounting effects are effected, e.g. loading data asynchronously.

To get around this you can apply some conditional rendering. In other words, keep the code you have, as-is, and wait until the data has been fetched, the local state updated, and the component rerendered, to render the `Chart` component with the now available data.

Example:

```
class GaantView extends React.Component {
  state = {
    rows: [],
    key: 0,
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const valori = await loadAttivita();

    const rows = valori.map(({ Descrizione }) => ([
      '2014Spring',
      Descrizione,
      'autumn',
      new Date(2014, 2, 22),
      new Date(2014, 5, 20),
      null,
      100,
      null,
    ]));

    this.setState({ rows });
  }

  render() {
    const { rows } = this.state;

    if (!rows.length) {
      return <div>Loading Row Data</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <p style={{ color: 'white', alignContent: 'center' }}>
          Diagramma Gaant
        </p>
        <Chart
          chartType="Gantt"
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          data={[columns, ...rows]}
          options={options}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    isFetching: state.auth.isFetching,
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
    errorMessage: state.auth.errorMessage,
  };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(GaantView));
```